# Easiest SQL command to show all rows and tables

Tags: sql

Let's say my database has the following columns: FirstName, LastName, SSN. I want to write a SQL statement that would show only columns and last name begin with a S.

I'm just a beginner so what is the easiest way to to do this?

```
SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname ="s",
  ssn
FROM
  Patrons
WHERE
  xtype = 'U';
GO
```

is this right?

Comment: You can just do Select * from table. It will select entire data from your table.

Answer (score 5):

The WHERE clause evaluates to only select rows who fulfill that requirement. So, you would only need:

```
SELECT *
FROM Patrons
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know where the "xtype" came from but to get everything from your table you should use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Patrons
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple to achieve what you are asking for, all you need to do is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Patrons WHERE xtype = 'U';
```

`SELECT *` - Means select all columns
`WHERE xtype = 'U'` - Means where any row with the column xtype is equal to U.

If you wish to show all records with no condition then remove the `WHERE` clause to make:

```
SELECT * FROM Patrons
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the SELECT clause to:

```
SELECT *
```

Also, I'm assuming you wanted that WHERE clause, because it's filtering out some of the values. The answer to your title is:

```
SELECT * FROM Patrons
```

Answer (score 0):

remove where cluase if you want to show all rows

```
SELECT
      firstname,
      lastname,
      ssn
    FROM
      Patrons
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for -

```
SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname,
  ssn
FROM
  Patrons
WHERE
  lastname like 'S%'
```